# Center button in middle of page

Tags: html, css

So in my HTML document I have:

```
<button id="scoll-btn">Scroll Down</button>
```

and my CSS is:

```
#scoll-btn {
  background: url('../img/arrow_down.png') no-repeat center;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Because, i'm using `text-indent` to hide my text I can't use `text-align: center;` to get my button to jump to the center of the page.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set `display: block` to the button element. Block level elements can be centered with left and right margins set to auto.

Learn more about [**Centering block level content**](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#block)

Also [**w3.org CSS: centering element**](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

```css
#scoll-btn {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/55x55') no-repeat center;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="scoll-btn">Scroll Down</button>
```

Comment: How did I miss that, thanks! Any reason `display: block` made it jump to the center?

Comment: Because `margin: 0 auto` works on block level elements :)

Comment: @ManojKumar Oh really? I've always thought there had to be a set width on the element for it to be centered, great!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `position:relative` , `left:calc(50% - 55px / 2)` , `50%` of parent element width minus `55px / 2` element width divided by two

```css
#scoll-btn {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/55/55/cats') no-repeat center;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 55px / 2);
}
```

```html
<button id="scoll-btn">Scroll Down</button>
```